# Quelle expression rendrait compte de l’idée qu’on souhaite parler de quelque chose en harmonie avec ce qui précède?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, constructions

Exemple.

> Je me pose la question de savoir s’il est usuel d’employer le verbe « remplacer » à la voix passive. **De même/ de la même manière/ à l’avenant** je me pose la même question concernant le verbe « substituer ».

Parenthèse :
« Concernant » dans la phrase qui précède est-il le terme adéquat ?
L’emploi de « sur » ou « à propos » serait-il mieux ?
Est-ce une bonne formulation ?

Que votre réponse soit affirmative ou négative, je souhaiterais que vous me présentiez d’autres tournures, histoire d’élargir l’horizon de mes connaissances.

Merci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*De même* est la meilleure des trois propositions, on peut aussi utiliser *dans le même ordre d'idée*. Le problème est la répétition des *même*.

Plutôt que *concernant*, j'utiliserais *à propos* ou *pour*.

Voici les deux phrases remaniées et simplifiées :

> Je me demande s’il est courant d’utiliser le verbe « remplacer » à la voix passive. Même question (ou : je me le demande aussi) pour le verbe « substituer ».

Answer (score 1):

Un ajout, inspiré d'une autre réponse, pour les « autres tournures ». Les phrases sont inutilement répétitives et on peut employer « au [passif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passif#Nom_commun) » plutôt qu'*à la voix passive* :

> Je me demande s'il est courant d'utiliser les verbes « remplacer » et
> « substituer » au passif.

J'ajouterais que l'« expression [qui] rendrait compte de l’idée qu’on souhaite parler de quelque chose en harmonie avec ce qui précède » est selon moi ici la *conjonction de coordination* ([*et*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/et)). Plus généralement, on peut regarder du côté des « [charnières](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5160) » employées pour marquer une [addition](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5159).